'Softening' a Velcro closure
I have a several pairs of slacks that use Velcro® closures for the pockets.
The issue is that they're much more aggressive and noisy to open than they need to be.
Is there a simple way to reduce the grip of such closures?

Just about any "aftermarket" or DIY method you'd use to soften the closure will also reduce the effectiveness of the closure. The noise is created by the hooks releasing from the loops.
The hooks can cease to maintain the hook shape or relax the shape somewhat, which will reduce the noise and force. Additionally, a loop can open, completely removing itself from the role of security.
In both cases, the result is minimal closure. I've worn uncounted footwear using this type of system and eventually given up on it for those reasons.
One can attach interference strips in strategic locations, basically the matching type of hook/loop material to remove some of the latching. Purchasing non-adhesive product from a sewing or material store and cutting it to short lengths will allow you to create a dotted line of "no-grip" area on the closure.
The advantage of this method is that when the exposed segments eventually fail, you can reposition the no-grip portions over the dead spots and "activate" the protected areas until it is necessary to replace the entire strip.

'Interference' sounds like a reasonable option. I'm not concerned about losing effectiveness over time, because, unlike shoes, these pocket closures are just peripherally useful, not vital to function.

An additional advantage with this method is the ability to make substantial changes over time, as it's effectively non-destructive.
